# (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ufw

Try to using ssh connect google cloud computer engine (macOs Catalina)

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-west1-b" "mac-vm" --project "mac-vm-282201"
```

and get error

```
ssh: connect to host 34.105.11.187 port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

and I try

```
ssh -I ~/.ssh/mac-vm-key asd61404@34.105.11.187
```

also get error

```
ssh: connect to host 34.105.11.187 port 22: Operation timed out
```

so I found this code to diagnose it

```
gcloud compute ssh —zone "us-west1-b" "mac-vm" —project "mac-vm-282201" —ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

return

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 34.105.11.187 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 34.105.11.187 [34.105.11.187] port 22.
```

I don't know, how can I fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

---

here is my recent Serial console

```
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm google_network_daemon[684]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm dhclient[684]: 
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm dhclient[684]: Listening on Socket/ens4
[   19.458355] google_network_daemon[684]: Listening on Socket/ens4
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm google_network_daemon[684]: Listening on Socket/ens4
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm dhclient[684]: Sending on   Socket/ens4
[   19.458697] google_network_daemon[684]: Sending on   Socket/ens4
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm google_network_daemon[684]: Sending on   Socket/ens4
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Starting Apply the settings specified in cloud-config...
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Auto import assertions from block devices being skipped.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Succeeded.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[   20.216129] cloud-init[718]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:config' at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:39 +0000. Up 20.11 seconds.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm cloud-init[718]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:config' at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:39 +0000. Up 20.11 seconds.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
Jul  4 02:28:39 mac-vm systemd[1]: Starting Execute cloud user/final scripts...
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm google-clock-skew: INFO Synced system time with hardware clock.
[   20.886105] cloud-init[725]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:final' at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:41 +0000. Up 20.76 seconds.
[   20.886430] cloud-init[725]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 finished at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:41 +0000. Datasource DataSourceGCE.  Up 20.87 seconds
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm cloud-init[725]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:final' at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:41 +0000. Up 20.76 seconds.
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm cloud-init[725]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 finished at Sat, 04 Jul 2020 02:28:41 +0000. Datasource DataSourceGCE.  Up 20.87 seconds
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Execute cloud user/final scripts.
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm systemd[1]: Reached target Cloud-init target.
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
Jul  4 02:28:41 mac-vm startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm startup-script: INFO startup-script: sudo: ufw: command not found
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 1.
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Succeeded.
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
Jul  4 02:28:42 mac-vm systemd[1]: Startup finished in 1.396s (kernel) + 20.065s (userspace) = 21.461s.
Jul  4 02:29:06 mac-vm systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jul  4 02:43:32 mac-vm systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jul  4 02:43:32 mac-vm systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Jul  4 02:43:32 mac-vm systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

Comment: Take a look on your [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) and see what is the error. The most common errors are: your VM is tull, the guest agent its unable to write data to the home folder or any other error. Add relevant information (the serial console log contains tons of information) to the question so we can see what is the error related to.